# How to search by sku with space in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, catalogsearch

I have face some problem in catalog search by SKU.

My sku is **PW 512/24**. It will give me multiple result for this SKU. 
Please help me How can I search product with SKU including space?

Thank you in adavance!

Comment: Could you explain what you exactly mean with "It will give me multiple result for this SKU" or give an example?
You should avoid having SKU's with space inbetween, better use hyphens or underscore.
When I change some SKU's (example: one to PW 123 and one to PW 124"), I get the right one product when I search for one of them.

Comment: Actualy whenever I am trying search with "PW 512/24" sku, But I get multiple search result.

Comment: How do your other SKU's look like?

Comment: Other SKU's look like, PW 214/14, 12548, RTV 54

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your search type to "Combined".

You will fine this in `System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog Search`

See [Search Type: Like, Full Text or Combined?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/search-type-like-full-text-or-combined)

Comment: Search Type is Like.

Comment: @PrashantParekh : Does solve your problem