# Spam bots & SQL Injections - How do I stop this?

Tags: magento-1.9, search, security

how do I stop this?

[image: screenshot]

Hundreds upon hundreds of these searches.

Comment: Make sue u have installed latest security patches. Find the cause from log, from where it's generating which page?

Comment: These are search terms people are using, how can I block these searches, from my research it looks like there trying to compromise my website.

Comment: Which Magento Version you are using? U have installed latest security patches??

Comment: Magento version 1.9.1.0

Comment: I'm still repeating have u installed latest security patches otherwise install latest Magento & check on that

Comment: I'll upgrade today and check overnight whether the same searches come through.

Comment: I recommend to check your server logs where these requests are coming from and also set up a firewall/web application firewall. If it's from one or only a few IPs you might set up a manual or automatic firewall rule to block these kind of requests (if they're sent within a short period of time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all:** These were blind attacks that most likely did not have any effect, a successful SQL injection should not be possible with these search queries.

### But it's still bad for two reasons:

1. the sheer number of these requests could take too many resources if they come in short time. As Anna Völk suggested in the comments, check your access logs if they come from certain IP ranges and block these IPs as soon as the requests start coming in.
2. other users will receive these searches as **suggestions** because they actually returned results. This is due to Magentos default `LIKE` search algorithm where you get all results where at least one word matches. Changing this from `OR` to `AND` improves the search results and makes searches like these return nothing, so that they won't show up as suggestions anymore.

#### See also:

[Search Type: Like, Full Text or Combined?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/search-type-like-full-text-or-combined/1190#1190)

> Quoting from jharrison.au's answer, change this:
>
> ```
> if ($like) {
>             $likeCond = '(' . join(' OR ', $like) . ')';
>         }
> ```
>
> To this:
>
> ```
> if ($like) {
>             $likeCond = '(' . join(' AND ', $like) . ')';
>         }
> ```
>
> To get an immediate, massive boost to the relevance of your search
> results.