# Strange search terms

Tags: magento-1.9, security, search-terms

I have some strange search terms in my magento admin panel. It looks like
 `1 waitfor delay '0:0:3' --`
 or 
`-1' OR 3 512-512-1=0 0 0 1 or '9WQxvY67'='`.
 I've looked into my log and it seems to be a googlebot: `66.249.75.146 - - [05/Sep/2017:00:17:41 +0300] "GET /catalogsearch/result/index/?dimensions=272&q=1+waitfor+delay+%270%3A0%3A3%27+-- HTTP/1.1" 200 15013 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"`.

The reverse lookup seems to be crawl-66-249-75-146.googlebot.com but I doubt google use delay statements and this is not the only ip, I have multiple starting with 66.249.x.x. It's not an option to block the class ip, since google use them and some services from google will not work.
Does anyone found a fix to this issue or has more info about it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If this is really the google bot and not somebody else masking as it, it is misused, e.g. by a page with links that will be crawled by Google.

You can find some more information about this type of requests in this similar question: [Spam bots & SQL Injections - How do I stop this?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132535/spam-bots-sql-injections-how-do-i-stop-this/132710#132710)