# Why am I getting unrelated items in my site search?

Tags: search, catalogsearch, search-terms

I've had a play around with various settings - previous to me running the site I realized that when you searched for something it wasn't bringing up anything related, as the site wasn't using descriptions/meta keywords or anything in the search.

For a one word search it now seems to work, but as soon as I added a number after it just brings up pages of non related items.

In this example I search "Linx" and it brings up the products where I have added the word linx to the meta keywords or description. As soon as I put "Linx 8" in it brings up lots of items that aren't related at all and don't have the term "linx 8" anywhere in the product pages.

I thought that maybe making it unable to search by SKU or price might help but it seems that it only made a small dent in the amount of items that are coming up.

I've only just started using magento so apologies if this is a quick fix  but I am stumped!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your configuration but it sounds like you're using a 'LIKE' based search which would scan your catalog for 'Linx' and '8' separately. Magento does have fulltext search capabilities which are more advanced.

[Reference this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/1190/36384) for a more comprehensive explanation of your options.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply! I realized that not long after posting this and it seemed to work, but then I logged in this morning to see that any search on the site was returning 0 results, even though it's worked fine the past week since I fixed it. I've reindexed everything and it looks like it's ok now...