# How to get specific sku product on search in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, search, sku

**In search bar when i am searching a product using sku (MY-PRODUCT-101)**,

It displays all the product whose sku is having **prefix** (MY-PRODUCT-XXX) ,

But i only want it to fetch whose sku is (MY-PRODUCT-101).

Answer (score 2):

Just create Plugin the customize and change the match strategie Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder\Match
and use around Plugin Function technique :

```
<?php
namespace Ibnab\OneSku\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Helper\Mysql\Fulltext;
use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Field\FieldInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Field\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\ScoreBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Request\Query\BoolExpression;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Request\QueryInterface as RequestQueryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Preprocessor\PreprocessorInterface;
use Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext as FulltextResource;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\Collection as AttributeCollection;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;
use Ibnab\OneSku\Helper\Data as OneSkuData;
class Match extends \Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder\Match {
    const SPECIAL_CHARACTERS = '-+~/\\<>\'":*$#@()!,.?`=%&^';
    const MINIMAL_CHARACTER_LENGTH = 3;
    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    private $replaceSymbols = [];
    /**
     * @var ResolverInterface
     */
    private $resolver;
    /**
     * @var Fulltext
     */
    private $fulltextHelper;
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $fulltextSearchMode;
    /**
     * @var PreprocessorInterface[]
     * @since 100.1.0
     */
    protected $preprocessors;
    /**
     * @var AttributeCollection
     */
    private $attributeCollection;
    /**
     * @var FulltextResource
     */
    private $fulltextResource;
    private $storeManager;
    private $_resource;</p>

<p>    /**
     * @var \Ibnab\PaymentFee\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $dataHelper;    
    /**
     * @param ResolverInterface $resolver
     * @param Fulltext $fulltextHelper
     * @param string $fulltextSearchMode
     * @param PreprocessorInterface[] $preprocessors
     */
    public function __construct(
    OneSkuData $dataHelper,AttributeCollection $attributeCollection, FulltextResource $fulltextResource, StoreManagerInterface $storeManage, ResourceConnection $resource, ResolverInterface $resolver, Fulltext $fulltextHelper, $fulltextSearchMode = Fulltext::FULLTEXT_MODE_BOOLEAN, array $preprocessors = []
    ) {        
        $this->resolver = $resolver;
        $this->replaceSymbols = str_split(self::SPECIAL_CHARACTERS, 1);
        $this->fulltextHelper = $fulltextHelper;
        $this->fulltextSearchMode = $fulltextSearchMode;
        $this->preprocessors = $preprocessors;
        $this->attributeCollection = $attributeCollection;
        $this->fulltextResource = $fulltextResource;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManage;
        $this->_resource = $resource;
        $this->dataHelper = $dataHelper;
        parent::__construct($resolver,$fulltextHelper, $fulltextSearchMode, $preprocessors);
    }
    public function aroundBuild($matcher, $build, $scoreBuilder, $select, $query, $conditionType
    ) {
        /** @var $query \Magento\Framework\Search\Request\Query\Match */
        $resultSku = 0;
        $queryValue = $this->prepareQuery($query->getValue(), $conditionType);
        $fieldList = [];
        foreach ($query->getMatches() as $match) {
            $fieldList[] = $match['field'];
        }
        $resolvedFieldList = $this->resolver->resolve($fieldList);
        $fieldIds = [];
        $columns = [];
        foreach ($resolvedFieldList as $field) {
            if ($field->getType() === FieldInterface::TYPE_FULLTEXT && $field->getAttributeId()) {
                $fieldIds[] = $field->getAttributeId();
            }
            $column = $field->getColumn();
            $columns[$column] = $column;
        }
        if ($this->dataHelper->allowExtension()) {
        $attribute = $this->attributeCollection->getItemByColumnValue('attribute_code', 'sku');
        $attributeId = $attribute ? $attribute->getId() : 0;
        if ($attributeId != 0) {
            $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
            $mainFullTextScope = $this->fulltextResource->getMainTable() . "_scope" . $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
            $tblFullTextScope = $connection->getTableName($mainFullTextScope);
            $resultSku = $connection->fetchOne('SELECT count(entity_id) FROM `' . $tblFullTextScope . '` WHERE attribute_id=' . $attributeId . ' And data_index=\'' . $query->getValue() . '\'');
        }
        }
        if ($resultSku == 1) {
            $matchQuery = 'data_index=\'' . $query->getValue() . '\'';
        }else{
            $matchQuery = $this->fulltextHelper->getMatchQuery(
                    $columns, $queryValue, $this->fulltextSearchMode
            );     
        }
            $matchQuery = $this->fulltextHelper->getMatchQuery(
                    $columns, $queryValue, $this->fulltextSearchMode
            ); 
        $scoreBuilder->addCondition($matchQuery, true);
        if ($fieldIds) {
            $matchQuery = sprintf('(%s AND search_index.attribute_id IN (%s))', $matchQuery, implode(',', $fieldIds));
        }
        $select->where($matchQuery);
        return $select;
    }
}
```

in this class we have added some line to test of sku with some reference is exist by example in table catalogsearch_fulltext_scope1 (related to store id 1)

```
$attribute = $this->attributeCollection->getItemByColumnValue('attribute_code', 'sku');
$attributeId = $attribute ? $attribute->getId() : 0;
if ($attributeId != 0) {
    $connection = $this->_resource->getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    $mainFullTextScope = $this->fulltextResource->getMainTable() . "_scope" . $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $tblFullTextScope = $connection->getTableName($mainFullTextScope);
    $resultSku = $connection->fetchOne('SELECT count(entity_id) FROM `' . $tblFullTextScope . '` WHERE attribute_id=' . $attributeId . ' And data_index=\'' . $query->getValue() . '\'');
}
```

if yes we change the clause where to be strict equal without Boolean match or like .

```
if ($resultSku == 1) {
    $matchQuery = 'data_index=\'' . $query->getValue() . '\'';
}else{
    $matchQuery = $this->fulltextHelper->getMatchQuery(
            $columns, $queryValue, $this->fulltextSearchMode
    );     
}
```

[You can visit the Full Course and download Free Extension for this task](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-get-one-search-result-by-sku)

Comment: This solution will not work for Magento2.4.x because Magento\Framework\Search\Adapter\Mysql\Query\Builder\Match doesn't exists in latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1 has feature to set which kind of search you want.

but in Magento 2 that feature removed so you need to customize that magento-search module

for more detail check this which describe in detail as how all search type works :
[Search type details](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/search-type-like-full-text-or-combined)

Comment: Hello, Ronak, I have gone through this path but there is no option to change type of search.

Comment: Sorry I had put Magento 1 path by mistake.

Comment: Magento 2 doesn't allow to select search type so you need to customize it.

Comment: Okay, Do uou have any idea in which file i have to do custom things? Can you please provide me the path of that particular file?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to introduce "exact" search is to extend existing query declared in magento2ce/app/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/etc/search_request.xml. Particullary `quick_search_container` request.
You need to add "term" query which is equivalent of "term" elastic search query - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html. You can find the examples of `term` request in the same file (`advanced_search_container` request).

The most reasonable place to extend is `request->queries->query[quick_search_container]`

Comment: A working module implementing this "term request" exact search for elastic search would be useful, do you have a working example @Andrey Kosonov ?