# Magento2 + Elasticsearch with special Char search

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.1, elasticsearch

i am using  Elasticsearch of M 2.3.1

i want to make search has to work with special char

that is if i search with "abc-123"

i am getting result of products which contain a string 
abc, 123 abc-123 123-abc

which cause unwanted products are also listing.

it should be something like abc-123*  (even wildcard is also not working )

can any one help me on this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get specific sku product on search in magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143980/how-to-get-specific-sku-product-on-search-in-magento-2)

Comment: @pradeep-kumar did you resolve this problem? I am seeing very poor results for elastic search queries for SKU with hypen i.e. ABC-XX-123