# Catalog Search result Wrong Result Magento 2

Tags: magento2.4, catalogsearch, elasticsearch

I am facing issue in the search result. I have installed Magento 2.4.0 and using Elasticsearch 7.0.
When I search for h397 it gives me 4 product count and if I search for h397-4 it gives me 1868 product count. Might Magento consider it as a separate value like h397 and 4. So how can I fix this issue?

Please check attached screenshot for more clarification.

[image]

Is there any solution?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143980/how-to-get-specific-sku-product-on-search-in-magento-2