# how can I search catalog products in plural

Tags: magento-1.9, search

I have a list of furniture items as my catalog products. When search with keyword 'table' it displays 112 records and displays 1 record for keyword 'tables'.
Here my question is does magento support plural search. 
I need to display all the 112 records while searching with keywords 'tables'. For this which method should prefer.please advice me i am new to magento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The options for search can be found in the backend under

> System > Catalog > Catalog search,

you probably have search type set to LIKE. You will potentially get better results using  `combining LIKE and FULLTEXT` mode.
[For more see here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/search-type-like-full-text-or-combined)